# How to do decryption of a file in Java/Android which is encrypted using RSACertificate.der and RSAPrivatekey.p12

Tags: java, android, encryption, private-key

I am working on Android application for Encryption and decryption using RSA algorithm.
My intention is to decry-pt a file which is encrypted by server using RSACertificate.der and RSAPrivatekey.p12 files.

Now I have a Example.encriptedfile, RSACertificat.der and RSAPrivatekey.p12  files
I would like to decrypt the above example.encrypted file using above keys in JAVA

The implementation for getting Privatekey 
And Decryption code using Cipher is

The file is example.encrypted file.

```
    byte[] descryptedData = null;
    try {
        byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        new FileInputStream(file).read(data)

        KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
        keystore.load(con.getAssets().open("rsaPrivate.p12"), "password".toCharArray());
        pk = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey("1", "password".toCharArray());

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pk );
        descryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return new String(descryptedData);
```

The exception getting for the fallowing code is

```
java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown key type passed to RSA
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineInit(CipherSpi.java:277)
at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineInit(CipherSpi.java:381)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:519)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:479)
```

So can any one provide the suggestions and solutions to implement this

Thanks in advance.

But same

Answer (score 0):

If it's encrypted with the private key it isn't encrypted at all, as anyone who can get the public key can decrypt it, which could be anybody.

If the intention was really to encrypt it, it should have been encrypted with the *public* key.

Possibly however the intention was to *sign* it, in which case what you have to do is *verify* it against the public key. For which you need the public key, which is in the certificate. So you load the certificate into a `Certificate,` using the `java.security.cert` API and then use a `java.security.Signature` object to verify the signature with, using the public key obtained from the `Certificate.`

Comment: Yes I am using the same API like    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
   keystore.load(con.getAssets().open("rsaPrivate.p12"), "password".toCharArray());
   pk = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey("1", "password".toCharArray());

Comment: The above code is able to getting Privatekey  but when doing decryption using           Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
   cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pk);
   descryptedData = cipher.doFinal(data);            Getting an exception of        java.security.InvalidKeyException: unknown key type passed to RSA
  at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.CipherSpi.engineInit(CipherSpi.java:277)

Comment: You don't seem to have read a word I said. In any case you need to post those exceptions and their entire stack traces and your code. Edit it into your question. And indicate which line number is which.